# srtool permission denied at end of build

Tags: runtime, srtool

```
error: failed to create directory `/build/runtime/target`

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I used this command:
`srtool build --package kabocha-runtime -r ./runtime`

I also tried to use absolute path but it cannot find the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options to solve this problem and you can find more information in [this issue](https://github.com/paritytech/srtool/issues/46).

In short, what you can do is pass the `--root` flag to the `srtool-cli`:

```
srtool build --root ....
```